# error reading file skin.json libgdx

Tags: java, json, eclipse, libgdx

I am trying to create a main menu for a game that my friends and I are are attempting to make.  We work with Eclipse + LibGdx, and I genuinely have no idea what I am doing.  I am using code directly from, and I have been unable to find *any* help on any blog/forum/tutorial. (http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2015/02/03/LibGDX-Video-Tutorial-Scene2D-UI-Widgets-Layout-and-Skins.

```
    package com.mygdx.game;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Dialog;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer; 
    import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ScreenViewport;

    public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Skin skin;  
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create () {

    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));
    stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

    final TextButton button = new TextButton("Click Me",skin,"default");
    button.setWidth(200);
    button.setHeight(50);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Click Message",skin);

    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
          dialog.show(stage);
          Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                dialog.hide();
             }
          }, 10);
       }
    });
    stage.addActor(button);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
 }

     @Override
     public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();

 }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {;}
}
```

uiskin.json file:

```
    {
     com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: Razer.fnt     } },
      com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
      default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font     },
      },

    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default:  {
    titleFont: default-font
         }
       }
    }
```

---

desktoplauncher:

```
    package com.mygdx.game.desktop;

    import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
    import com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame;

    public class DesktopLauncher {
        public static void main (String[] arg) {
            LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new       LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), config);
    }
}
```

---

errors:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.(Skin.java:74)
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:26)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:694)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Font file not found: Razer.fnt
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$3.read(Skin.java:452)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$3.read(Skin.java:443)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:884)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:408)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:852)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:429)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:418)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:414)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:884)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:408)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692)
    ... 5 more
```

Thanks. Keep in my mind I am completely lost and am on my last resort.  Sorry about any mistakes I made in this post!!

-ed

Answer (score 2):

That error is basically saying there's something wrong with the skin json.

The format though seems pretty fine, however I think there is more in the stacktrace. Please check out the path to Razer.fnt.

If that doesn't fix it, paste here the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

```
Font file not found: Razer.fnt
```

You have to use [Hiero tool](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html) to create a Font. Put the two files generated in android project on Assets folder. If you dont have the "Razer font", search in some font site